# AJAX запрос

Tags: ajax, php, запрос

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать `ajax` запрос к файлу `poz.php`, результатом работы последнего являться переменная `$img` - изображение

Возможно ли изображения из `$img` поместить в глобальную переменную из скрипта `JS var img`?

```
var img;
    $ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/images/poz.php",
        dataType: // что здесь писать? ,
        success: function image(data){
`           img = data;
          `},
    error: function(){
              alert('Проблема с загрузкой скрипта');
          }
                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "/images/pos.php";
```

Comment: '

    img.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('image').src = this.src;
    }
    img.onerror = function() {
        alert('The image could not be loaded.');
    }

Comment: Юрий спасибо! ваш ответ был полезен!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url:"/images/poz.php",
  type:"POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  success:function(result){ 
    var images = '';
    for (var n in result)
      images += '<img src="'+result[n].filename+'" />';
  }
});
```

Т.е. тебе надо вернуть лишь путь к картинке и все

Comment: а вы уверены что на выходе мы должны получить json строку?
Ведь мы работаем с изображением?

Comment: вообще не рекомендуется хранить изображения в БД. лучше хранить или пути к ним или их названия.